# Android search google using volley/ retrofit

Tags: android, json, android-volley, google-search, retrofit

In my android application I want to search google for a particular query and get the response in json format using volley or retrofit. How can I implement that?

[I tried this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28771651/google-search-with-retrofit?rq=1)

I added volley as a library and wrote below code

```
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
String url = "http://www.google.com";

JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(url, 
    new Response.Listener<JSONArray> () {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            try {
                VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, 
    new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
        }
    });

    queue.add(req);
```

Comment: You should probably start by opening an IDE and start typing some code.

Comment: i tried volley. but i get the an html page in response.

Comment: Atleast post some code.What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

By making calls to `www.google.com` you will always have an HTML response, in order to get response with other format (Json) you should take a look at [Google Custom Search](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview).

Retrofit or Volley are helpers to make HTTP requests but can not change server response format or parse HTML to JSON.

Comment: what are current recommendations: volley or retrofit?